# OpenJDK java.sql.Timestamp different from Sun Java VM's timestamp class?

Tags: scala, timestamp, java

Is this difference due to a system setting or is it due to the a code difference?

OpenJDK Version:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.8.1.final (OpenJDK Client VM, Java 1.6.0_20).    
scala> new java.sql.Timestamp(1292141899648L)
res0: java.sql.Timestamp = 2010-12-12 08:18:19.648
```

Sun Java Version:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.8.1.final (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_24).
scala> new java.sql.Timestamp(1292141899648L)
res0: java.sql.Timestamp = 2010-12-12 00:18:19.648
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like a difference in default timezone settings, so that timestamp is the same, but its representations in output are different. Check results of `TimeZone.getDefault()`.